# jQuery css visibility not working within load method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a script so that when this div `#events` is clicked the content currently in `#meet` div changes it's visibility to hidden (so that space is preserved) and then using jquery load method, the content in v2.html is loaded into the `#meet` div. However, right now the `#meet` div disappears but the new content does not appear. Any ideas why?

HTML:

```
<div id="meet">
........
<div id="exec"></div>
........
</div>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#exec").click(function(){
            $("#meet").load("execute.html").fadeIn('slow');
        });
        $("#events").click(function() {
            $('#meet').css('visibility','hidden', function() {
               $('#meet').load("ev2.html", function() {
                   $('#meet').css('visibility', 'visible');
               })
            })
        });
    });
```

Comment: `.css` doesn't take a function as a third parameter. It does take a function as a second parameter with only a `propertyName` as the first: http://api.jquery.com/css/. Try removing that function call and moving `$('#meet').load()` to just below the first `.css` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.css` doesn't take a function as a third parameter. It does take a function as a second parameter with only a `propertyName` as the first: [api.jquery.com/css](http://api.jquery.com/css). Try removing that function call and moving `$('#meet').load()` to just below the first `.css` call.

You can chain the `.css` and `.load` functions as well.

```css
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#exec").click(function(){
    $("#meet").load("execute.html").fadeIn('slow');
  });
  $("#events").click(function() {
    $('#meet').css('visibility','hidden').load("ev2.html", function() {
        $('#meet').css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use CSS class instead in JQuery : addClass("foo") which contains the style you want and removeClass("boo") which contains the style you don't want.

look at this fiddle [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/alanmehio/73bzveoh/4/)

```
$("#navigation").on("click", function(){
     if($(this).hasClass("foo")){
        $(this).removeClass("foo");
        $(this).addClass("boo");  
        $(this).animate({width: 100}, 350);
     } else {
        $(this).removeClass("boo");
        $(this).addClass("foo");  
        $(this).animate({width: 100}, 350);
     }   
});
```